# How to execute generic method by setting double generic using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class and it has generic method:

```
   public class MyClass
   {
      public void MyMethod<T, IEntity>()
      {

      }
   }
```

In some places I'm executing it using reflection:

```
        var intType = typeof(int);
        var stringType = typeof(string);
        MethodInfo method = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod(nameof(MyClass.MyMethod));
        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(intType, stringType);
        generic.Invoke(myClass, null);
```

It works. In some cases I need to use Action in method:

```
myClass.MyMethod<Action<int>, string>();
```

How can I do that using reflection?

Comment: `typeof(Action<int>)`?

Comment: What if int comes as Type?

Comment: `typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(someType)`

Comment: @Sweeper Could you post it as answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the first generic parameter at compile time to be `Action<int>`, then you could just use `typeof(Action<int>)`:

```
var actionType = typeof(Action<int>);
var stringType = typeof(string);
MethodInfo method = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod(nameof(MyClass.MyMethod));
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(actionType, stringType);
generic.Invoke(myClass, null);
```

If the generic parameter of `Action` is only known at runtime as an instance of `Type`, you can call [`MakeGenericType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype?view=netframework-4.8) on `typeof(Action<>)` to construct the action type at runtime:

```
var actionType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(someTypeObject);
var stringType = typeof(string);
MethodInfo method = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod(nameof(MyClass.MyMethod));
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(actionType, stringType);
generic.Invoke(myClass, null);
```